# QTableView Headers getting wrapped, how to make them normal?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I wrote a QT GUI application using c++, here when I enter a sqlite3 DB table's name, the program performs a **select * (table_name)** and shows the output in a QTableView model. I have used,

```
    this->model1=new QSqlQueryModel();
    model1->setQuery(MyQuerySqlite);
    ui->sqlite_tableView->setModel(model1);
```

It works perfectly but in the output table view the headers are getting wrapped, I am attaching the actual application screenshot,

[image: application screenshot]

here you can see only **STINATION_** is visible from **DESTINATION_ID** and **OMMAND_I** is visible from **COMMAND_ID**. How can I modify the code of QTableView to ensure all the column headers are shown properly ??? i.e. DESTINATION_ID, COMMAND_ID etc etc fully.

Comment: Try to call resizeColumnToContents. It works with data but maybe with header too.

Comment: i dont know why it didnt work earlier, but now, ui->sqlite_tableView->resizeColumnsToContents(); did the trick.. thank you.

Comment: In this case I posted this as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this try to call special method `resizeColumnsToContents()` to resize all columns or call `resizeColumnToContents(int col)` to resize specific column.

It will work with model data and with header data too.